# re-map MQTT topic in mosquitto bridge?

Tags: mosquitto

I'm trying to help a customer connect their Mosquitto bridge to Azure IoT Edge.  They have some legacy equipment that speaks MQTT, but because it can't do TLS and the topics can't be changed, we are trying to run the messages through the Mosquitto MQTT Broker, and over to IoT Edge via the Mosquitto bridge...

I've had no problems getting the actual connection made from the bridge to IoT Edge and I have messages flowing to the bridge.  That connectivity works fine.  The problem comes in the topics.  I really can't change the topic structure that the client publish on.  However, IoT Edge requires messages to be published on a specific MQTT topic (devices//messages/events).    Where device_id is the name of my broker, let's say 'mymqttbroker' just for fun.

So, what I'm trying to do is to take the messages that some in on pretty much any topic, and resend those messages through the bridge on the devices/mymqttbroker/messages/events topic to IoT Edge.

I know the topic line in the bridge config has the remote_prefix and local_prefix parameters, but that won't cut it.  Per [this](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-bridge-configuration/) article, it says you can't do this..

"E.g A broker would receive messages to topic sensor1 and remap them to new_sensor1.  Currently this form of remapping is not available,"

Any idea how to do something like this?  is it possible?   Essentially, is there any way in the bridge to accept messages from any topic, and republish them on a specific fixed topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to write a little helper app that subscribes to the old topics and republishes to the new topics, then just bridge the new topics.

It does add another point of failure, but it's the only option for mosquitto.

If you are not wedded to mosquitto, you can build your own custom broker with something link mosca and add the remapping into the broker.

Comment: Thanks for both the confirmation that I can't do this with mosquitto itself, and the ideas for work arounds.  Very helpful.  The customer in question is pretty much married to mosquitto, but would probably be ok with the helper app.